# An observation regarding conversion between geodetic latitude and geocentric latitude

Tags: convert

Over at physics.stackexchange someone noticed the something interesting about conversion between geodetic latitude and geocentric latitude:

Given: at 45 degrees latitude, height zero, the difference between geodetic latitude and geocentric latitude is about 0.2 degree.

From a physics point of view: for every latitude one can calculate how much centripetal acceleration is required to remain co-rotating with the Earth. At every latitude: providing required centripetal acceleration goes at the expense of inverse-square-law gravitational acceleration.

For instance, to co-rotate with the Earth along the Equator requires 0.0339 meter per second per second acceleration. That is part of the reason why at the Equator gravitational acceleration is less than at the poles.

At 45 degrees latitude the calculation gives that the amount of required centripetal acceleration corresponds to a plumb line hanging at an angle of about 0.1 degree.

Now, that angle cannot be *measured*, because inertial mass is equivalent to gravitational mass. That angle of 0.1 degree (at 45  degrees latitude) can only be *inferred*.

What is measurable is the effective gravitational acceleration. So the inferred angle is the angle between effective gravitational acceleration and the follows-from-inverse-square-law gravitational acceleration. That angle will stand in some relation to the Earth's ellipsoid shape.

Anyway, one is 0.2 degree, the other is 0.1 degree. Maybe that factor 2 is a coincidence, maybe there is a neat mathematical reason for it.

I'm curious whether this is a known thing.
(Then again, it could be that conversion between geodetic and geocentric has been moved to software so long ago that only a few old people still have ready knowledge of such conversion.)

---

[Later addition]
[Posted 10 hours after originally submitting the question]

Let me expand on the physics of the Earth's rotation

There is the [equivalence of inertial and gravitational mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass#Inertial_vs._gravitational_mass).

Recapitulating the concept of 'level':
On any celestial body there are two methods to ascertain what the local level surface is: you can use a spirit level or a water level to create a surface that is perpendicular to the local direction of gravitational acceleration, or you can use a plumb line to establish the direction that is parallel to the local direction of gravitational acceleration. As we know: those two methods will always be in agreement with each other.

About celestial bodies:
A sufficiently large celestial body will over geological time contract to the shape of lowest possible potential energy.

A non-rotating celestial body contracts to a sphere.
Obviously, just from geometrical symmetry it follows that on non-rotating sphere the direction of gravitational acceleration is everywhere perpendicular to the physical surface.

A rotating celestial body has an equatorial bulge; in the case of the Earth the magnitude of the equatorial bulge is described in terms of the reference ellipsoid.

For the purpose of this discussion the difference between the reference ellipsoid and the [Geoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoid) is negligable. For the remainder of this discussion it should be granted that the measuring apparatus is *not sensitive enough* to sense the shape of the Geoid.

Over geological time scale the Earth equatorial bulge settles to a state of lowest possible energy; it's an equilibrium shape.

On the rotating Earth:
The water in the oceans does not have a tendency to flow to the Equator, nor a tendency to flow to the poles. At every latitude there is equilibrium.

(As is well known, ice ages affect this solid Earth equilibrium. When an ice cover that was kilometers thick melts away the local Earth crust is no longer supporting that weight, and that area of local Earth crust rebounds, affecting direction of local water flow. All that falls in the category of the shape of the Geoid.)

On the rotating Earth:
On any latitude a plumb line points in a direction perpendicular to the local reference ellipsoid surface.

The Equator is further away from the Earth's geometric center than the poles.
If a celestial body would have the same ellipsoid shape as the Earth, but non-rotating, then an object starting close to the "Equator" would slide all the way *downhill* to the nearest pole.

In the case of the Earth the redistribution of the mass of the solid Earth is such that the downhill slope of the equatorial bulge is providing the required centripetal force for the Earth's oceans to remain co-rotating with the Earth, without tendency to shift to another latitude. At every latitude there is an equilibrium.

I cannot emphasize this enough:
It follows from the equivalence of inertial and gravitational mass that a plumb line hangs perpendicular to the local level surface, at every latitude.

For each latitude we can calculate how much centripetal acceleration is required to remain co-rotating with the Earth at that latitude.

In the case of [circular motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_motion): formula for required centripetal acceleration:
angular velocity squared, times the radial distance.

The Earth angular velocity is slow, and then you have to square it, so you get a number with a *lot* of leading zeros, which would be hard to read. So I only give the significant figures, but of course I do make sure that the number for the required centripetal acceleration has the correct number of leading zeros.

The significant figures of the square of the Earth angular velocity: 5.31

The significant figures of the Earth radius at 45 degrees latitude: 4.50

Required centripetal acceleration at 45 degrees latitude: 0.0239 meters per second squared.

For comparison: at the Equator the required centripetal acceleration to remain co-rotating with the Earth is 0.0339 meters per second squared. Providing this required centripetal acceleration goes at the expense of the inverse-square-law gravitational acceleration, resulting in a *measured* gravitational acceleration of about 9.78 meters per second squared. As we all know: a [gravimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravimetry) measures a single value: at the Equator about 9.78 meters per second squared.

At any latitude not on the Equator or the poles the required centripetal acceleration must be decomposed into a component parallel to the local surface, and a component perpendicular to the local surface.

For this assessment only the component *parallel* to the local surface is relevant.

At 45 degrees latitude, required centripetal acceleration in the direction parallel to the local surface:
sin(45 degrees) * 0.0239 = 0.0169 meters per second squared

Corresponding angle:
arcsin(0.0169/9.80) is about 0.1 degree

Further reading: an answer that I posted on physics stackexchange (May 2021), about [the process of providing the required centripetal acceleration](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/636561/17198)

---

I'm mostly active on Physics Stackexchange. To get an idea of where I stand you can visit [my physics stackexchange profile page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/17198/cleonis)

Comment: If the Earth were a sphere of homogeneously distributed mass, what would be the deviation of the gravity vector (force per unit mass, or acceleration) from the direction of the center of mass at 45 degrees latitude?

Answer (score 3):

If the Earth were spherical, of homogeneously distributed mass, rotating at constant angular velocity, alone in the universe without the influence of other celestial bodies, we could mathematically model its gravitational field.

Any equipotential surface of that field is likely not to have a strictly ellipsoidal shape, just as the Earth does not, just as it does not have uniformly distributed masses nor is it alone in the universe.

But, if we suppose that the Earth was malleable enough to take the form of an equipotential surface of its gravitational field, and that this was ellipsoidal, the direction of the gravity vector applied to a point on its surface would be the same as the direction normal to the ellipsoidal surface that passes through that point. And the angle that this normal forms with the plane of the equator is its geodetic latitude.

So why could you find differences between the direction of the gravity vector and the normal to the ellipsoid in your model?

What occurs to me is that the centripetal and centrifugal components of gravity are being calculated based on a spherical Earth and its geocentric latitude. Distance to central axis in the ellipsoid must be computed from the prime vertical radius of curvature and geodetic latitude instead.

Do not forget that the ellipsoidal surface is just a mathematical abstraction that we make, and that neither the Earth nor an equipotential surface of its gravitational field has exactly that shape. The relationships you are trying to describe are between physical and geometric geodesy.

In the geometric question of geodesy, the tangent of the geocentric latitude of a point is a function of the tangent of the geodetic latitude, so that:

tan(Ψ) = (1-e²).tan(θ)

where e² is the square of the first eccentricity:

e² = 1-(b²/a²) = 2f-f²